# Wordpress ACF field update after getting the value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this action that retrieves the crop values when I crop an image in the image editor and update the value in the db record (with `update_field()`.
So I can update the value of the field in the database, but I don't know how to set the value of the field in the post editor. The field value remains blank and when the user update the post the value is being overwritten by with null value.
How can I do?

```
add_action( 'wp_save_image_editor_file', 'save_crop_data');
function save_crop_data(){
    $attachment_id = $_REQUEST['postid'];
    $parent = get_post_ancestors($attachment_id);
    $post_id = $parent[0];
    update_field('crop_data', $_REQUEST['history'], $post_id);
    return $saved;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'portfolio_admin_script' );
function portfolio_admin_script() {
    global $post_type;
    if( 'portfolio' == $post_type )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'portfolio-admin-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/portfolio.js', array( 'jquery', 'media-editor' ), '', true );
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT** (file portfolio.js)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        //intercept the ajax event on media library close
        if (typeof settings.data === 'string' && /action=get-post-thumbnail-html/.test(settings.data) && xhr.responseJSON && typeof xhr.responseJSON.data === 'string') {
            var crop_data_stored = decodeURIComponent(getCookie("crop_values"));
            crop_data_stored = crop_data_stored.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
            if (crop_data_stored != '' && $('#acf-field-crop_data').val() == '') {
                jQuery('#acf-field-crop_data').val(crop_data_stored);
                deleteCookie("crop_values");
            }
        }
    });

    function getCookie(name) {
        var value = "; " + document.cookie;
        var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
        if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    }
    function deleteCookie(name) {
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
    };
});
```